# Require minimum filter input length with TomSelect (like select2's minimumInputLength)

Tags: javascript, tom-select

I have a webpage with a multi-select field for names, and to prevent biases, I want to only show list entries to users after they have entered at least 3 characters into the filter/search field.

Select2 supports this using the [`minimumInputLength`](https://select2.org/searching#minimum-search-term-length) setting ([jsbin](https://jsbin.com/jehaxinaju/1/edit?html,js,output))

What would be the best way to achieve this with TomSelect?
[jsbin-template for tomselect here](https://jsbin.com/nokakigade/1/edit?html,js,output)

Their documentation lists the `shouldLoad` setting as a possibility, with this explanation:

> Use the shouldLoad() callback to implement minimum input length or other input validation. If the callback returns false, load() will not be called and the not_loading template will be added to the dropdown instead of the loading or no_results templates.

However, it seems that `shouldLoad` only limits whether `load()` will be called to fetch additional results from the remote resource, but any results that are already available will always be shown, no matter what `shouldLoad` returns ([jsbin mre](https://jsbin.com/badotukahi/1/edit?html,js,output)).

Comment: After digging through tomselect code a bit more, I think there is currently no way to achieve this, so I started a github discussion on their repo [here](https://github.com/orchidjs/tom-select/discussions/376).

Answer (score 0):

**shouldLoad** works, you have to return on callback when you satisfy with the query, **load** will only call the api if the return of shouldLoad is true shouldLoad?
You can set minimun, regex, or any validation that you want.

```
new TomSelect("#your_select", {
    valueField: "id",
    labelField: "name",
    searchField: "name",
    shouldLoad: function (query, callback) {
        if (query.length > 3) {//if search has at least 4 chars
            return true;
        }
    },
    load: function (query, callback) {
        var url = "/your/url/remote/" + encodeURIComponent(query);
        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
                callback(json);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                callback();
            });
    },
});
```

For remove your previous results, you can use **clear()** to clear selected and **removeItem** before each load.